# How do i run the oracle client server tutorial?

Tags: java, oracle, client, client-server

I am trying to implement [the tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) but I don't understand how to run it.

I've done the following:

1. create 2 java projects, one with the client source file and the other project containing the server and protocol code
2. go into my command prompt and cd into my server project directory
3. set the path into the java directory and the jdk directory
4. type javac with the `.java` file names after to create the `.class` file
5. type java KnockKnockProtocol

   > Error: Main method not found in class KnockKnockProtocol, please define the main method as:
   >   public static void main(string[] args)
6. type java KnockKnockServer
   and then the terminal screen would not let me type anything else

I am a complete beginner at java and doing this all for the first time. Therefore I really don't do much. I'm not even sure if what i am doing is correct. Can someone guide me a little please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in the above mentioned tutorial the `KnockKnockServer.java` is the server class which creates the server socket.

`KnockKnockProtocol.java` is the protocol that the client and server use to communicate.

The entry point of the java program is main method:

```
     public static void main(String... args){}
```

Start the server with the following commands:

```
     javac KnockKnockServer.java
     java KnockKnockServer
```

Comment: How do i continue after I type java KnockKnockServer then? Since the curser just stops and doesn't allow me to type anything else afterwards. Is this supposed to happen? And if it is, how can I continue to open the client?

Comment: ok something happened when I try again but it said 'could not listen on port 4444'. But i have no idea which port i should try to place it in? I don't really know much about this and I didn't really get any good google results. Help please!

Comment: 'could not listen on port 4444' means there might be another program running on that port (in this case your server.)
You can open another terminal and run the client from there which should connect to your running server.